# How to change the browser of a web-shortcut?

Tags: lineageos, home-screen-shortcuts, 8.1-oreo, trebuchet

An incompatibility between F-Droid's current version of IceCat and Android 8, makes it that I can't `Add to home screen` from IceCat (well, I can, but it doesn't do anything other than jump back to Trebuchet).

How can I create a web-shortcut to IceCat in that case?

I figured I could create a web shortcut with another browser, but it seems those shortcuts are "bound" to their original browser, so even though IceCat is my default browser, the web shortcut opens up in another browser.

Maybe another way to ask this, is: how to create a web shortcut which is not specific to any browser, so when I click it I get asked which browser to use.

Comment: I didn't know about IceCat :). Anyway, it can be done if you have pro version of Nova launcher- just tried

Comment: I don't see it in F-droid.  Is it Free Software?  Also, it sounds like it's a launcher, hence a replacement for Trebuchet.  Can it make/modify a shortcut that Trebuchet will know how to use?

Comment: It's a launcher on Play Store. Free and paid. Only paid version can do this. I haven't used Trebuchet. You can download free version and see

Comment: Once it is installed it should replace Trebuchet and the paid version I tested with your browser and what you want can be achieved. It's very rich in customisation and hence very popular

Comment: For the functionality beeshyams describes (and I vaguely remember that from Apex launcher, which is quite similar), could [ActivityLauncher](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.szalkowski.activitylauncher/) fit? Haven't used it myself so I don't know if it can edit already existing shortcuts.

Comment: Hello Stefan. In response to your preference of requiring a solution which is free/libre in character I posted [this meta question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/96277), and according to the response received as the solution as well as my own understanding of the scope of this site I am asking you to please do no dismiss answers on account of that preference. I have thus removed your comments which dismissed comments and answers where solution was not libre/free. If you cannot part with this preference I suggest you consider asking on [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

Try [Website Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deltacdev.websiteshortcut). Open the app, paste the link of the website/webpage, then click on create shortcut. It will fetch the icon from the website for you.

On the home screen, click on the shortcut, you will be prompted to choose a browser. After selecting your browser, I advise to select "Just once" to allow the selection of other browsers if needed.

The disadvantage of the app is that if you remove it, the shortcuts will also be removed.

**Disclaimer:** I am not related to the app's developer.

**EDIT:** Below his the response I received from the app's developer as to why the source code is unavailable. He has given his authorisation to show the screenshot of his response.

[image]